# За счёт чего работает конструкция "функция()()"?

Tags: javascript

```
const sum = (a) => {
  let sum = a;
  const func = (b) => {
    if (b) {
      sum += b;
      return func;
    } else {
      return sum;
    }
  };
  return func;
};
sum(2)(3)()
```

Есть такая функция, за счёт чего можно функцию так вызывать?
Вторые скобочки - это аргумент или это другой вызов функции?

Comment: Не понятно что вы имеете ввиду, любые скобки это вызов функции здесь. Первые скобки – вызываем sum, получаем функцию func, вторые скобки – вызываем func, получаем опять func, третьи скобки – вызов func, получаем накопленный результат

Answer (score 8):

1. `sum(2)`: вызывается функция `sum`, в качестве аргумента передаётся `2`
2. `sum(2)(3)`: результат выполнения `sum(2)` вызывается как функция, в качестве аргумента передаётся `3`. К ошибке это не приводит, так как `sum` действительно возвращает функцию (`func`)
3. `sum(2)(3)()`: результат выполнения `sum(2)(3)` вызывается как функция, аргументы не передаются. К ошибке это также не приводит, так как `func` в данном случае возвращает функцию (`func`)

---

Вызов `sum(2)()()` или `sum(2)(0)()`, например, привёл бы к ошибке:

> Uncaught TypeError: sum(...)(...) is not a function

потому что в этом случае `func` вернёт число (`sum`), а не функцию